# getting size 0 when creating a File in javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I'm trying to create a file from some base64 data i get from the camera plugin in Ionic. I'm using a function i got from another stackoverflow's answer.
The problem is that the file created has size: 0 and the name property seems to be the Uint8array I pass on creation.

This is the function to convert the Base64 data: (the first two lines are commented because the data doesn't have the "data:image/jpeg;base64," beginning)

```
_dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    let //arr = dataurl.split(','),
        //mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(dataurl),
        n = bstr.length,
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:'image/jpeg'});
  }
```

this is what I get in the console:

```
File {name: Array(1), localURL: "archivo", type: {…}, lastModified: null, lastModifiedDate: null, …}
end: 0
lastModified: null
lastModifiedDate: null
localURL: "archivo"
name: [Uint8Array(268175)]
size: 0
start: 0
type: {type: "image/jpeg"}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: The line that confuses to me: `name: [Uint8Array(268175)]`. What filename do you have that is 260KB long? Did you check the arguments you pass to `_dataURLtoFile()`?

Comment: @Thomas The name i passed is the word "archivo" (means file in spanish) that you can see in the property "local URL". I dont get either why the array appears in the name property

Comment: Try without the `[]` around the file data as it is already an array, `return new File(u8arr, filename, {type:'image/jpeg'});`

Comment: well, you're not dealing with [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) but instead with [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file). Thanks to their excellent Documentation: *"If you're building a serious project, you can't afford to spend hours troubleshooting. Ionic's experts offer official maintenance, support, and integration help"*, I was able to get the actual interface for this constructor: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/5e12b5e9f63b12aef5198e9a72ac8d7b8e834442/www/File.js#L31 by using the search in github

Comment: @braza i get "Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPart[]'.
  Type 'Uint8Array' is missing the following properties from type 'BlobPart[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 3 more."

Comment: @Thomas yes, i had installed the File plugin. I deleted it but keep gettin the same output in the console

Comment: if you still get the same output, then the plugin ain't gone. Because JS' File has no `localURL` property.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the output of this function (the file)? Maybe there is another solution if you can't remove the File plugin

Comment: @braza send it to a server in FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question that `File` has been overwritten I've modified the function to use a `Blob` instead of `File`, then it will generate a `File` from that.

For demo purposes I have also overridden the default `File` with another function. I've also made it output the file in the DOM to show it has loaded the correct data.

```js
window.File = () => 'brokenfilefunction'
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
  let bstr = atob(dataurl),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while(n--){
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }
  // Something has overwritten File, so you can't use it
  // return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:'image/jpeg'});

  // Adding the blob to FormData converts it to an actual file
  const formData = new FormData();
  const blob = new Blob([u8arr], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
  formData.append(filename, blob);
  // Instead of getting the file, you could just send the formdata object in your request
  const actualFile = formData.entries().next().value[1];

  return actualFile;
}

const image = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';


const file = dataURLtoFile(image, 'name');
console.log(file);

// Display image in dom for demo
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById('image').src = fr.result;
}
fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```

```html
File has correctly been initialized to red dot:
<img id="image" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" />
```

Comment: after i deleted the plugin i needed it again, so i had to reinstall it. This works, thank you